# Draw isocele triangle according to angle in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, html5-canvas, triangle

I would like to know how can I draw an isocele triangle in canvas, if I know the first angle, and the lengths of the two equal side.

[Shema (known lengths are in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daR5L.png)

And second question, is it possible to curve the top side like that :

[Shema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa393.png)

Comment: you'd use canvas methods to draw and yes, you can do an arc like that - what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   ctx.closePath();
    ctx.save();

function drawPie(ctx,centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle ){
    
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
        ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

drawPie(ctx, 200,200,200,  -0.65*Math.PI, -0.60* Math.PI + Math.PI/4);
```

```html
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: While the code was what the questioner wanted, it would be more helpful to future readers, more generalisable, if you could explain what you had done.